# What is the difference between the elsarticle-num and elsarticle-num-names bibliography styles?

Tags: elsarticle, bibliographystyle

Apropos the `elsarticle-num` and `elsarticle-num-names` bibliography styles, the README says that the first one is "for numerical
references", and the second "for numerical
references + new natbib option". The documentation says that "the first one can be used for the numbered scheme, second one for numbered with new options of natbib.sty".

I am having trouble parsing this: I have been unable to find out what "new options of natbib.sty" is supposed to mean.

When I apply the two styles, the output looks superficially similar, but when I compare the source code I see many (small) differences. For example, `elsarticle-num` has an extra `lastchecked` field, while `elsarticle-num-names` has an extra `collaboration` field.

What I would like to know is what the conceptual difference is. Does `elsarticle-num-names` supersede `elsarticle-num`? And if not, how can I find out which style a journal I am submitting to requires?